# how to search the number in text box using javascript

Tags: jquery

For example if user is type 99999999 in text box as a value, this time i want to through a alert msg

I try it but not working

```
$('#text').on('change', function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   var valNine = val.search(/9/gi);
    if(valNine.length >= 8){
        alert('yes');
    }else{
        alert('no');
    }
});
```

i checked in console error message is showing 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null**

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for. We might guess, but, maybe that won't be what you're looking for...

Comment: can u check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `val.match(/9/g)`. See the below example.

```
$('#text').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var valNine = val.match(/9/g);
  if (valNine.length >= 8) {
      alert('yes');
  } else {
      alert('no');
  }
});
```

```js
$('#text').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var valNine = val.match(/9/g);
  if (valNine.length >= 8) {
    alert('yes');
  } else {
    alert('no');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```